# The relation between "docker/swarm" and "docker/swarmkit"

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am already familiar with [docker/swarm](https://github.com/docker/swarm), but find there occurs a "new" project: [docker/swarmkit](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit). But unfortunately, after reading the [README](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/master/README.md), I still can't figure out what is the function of `docker/swarmkit`. Could anyoone help to elaborate the relations between `docker/swarm` and `docker/swarmkit`? Why is `docker/swarmkit` born?

Comment: To add to confusion there is  Swarm mode in docker 1.12. So now we have old swarm, swarm kit and  new swarm mode in 1.12.

Comment: @atv I understand new Swarm mode in Docker 1.12 is integrating and enhancing Docker Swarm functions into Docker. But what is the Swarm kit?

Comment: I found this blog post really useful to understand difference between swarm standalone/swarmkit and docker 1.12 swarm mode https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/comparing-swarm-swarmkit-and-swarm-mode/

(yes there are actually *3* different products largely overlapped )

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Docker Swarm** is an older (2014) Docker native orchestration tool. It is *standalone* from the Docker engine and serves to connect Docker engines together to form a cluster. It's then possible to connect to the Swarm and run containers on the cluster. Swarm has a few features:

- Allows you to specify a discovery service (consul etc...)
- Some control over where containers are placed (using filters / constraints / distribution strategies, etc...)
- Exposes the same API as the Docker engine itself, allowing 3rd-party tools to interact seamlessly

**Swarmkit** is a new (2016) tool developed by the Docker team (most of which came out of the SocketPlane acquisition I believe) which provides functionality for running a cluster and distributing tasks (*note: not necessarily Docker containers*) to the machines in the cluster. The readme for Swarmkit is very good, and here are the main features as advertised:

- Distributed: SwarmKit uses the Raft Consensus Algorithm in order to coordinate and does not rely on a single point of failure to perform decisions.
- Secure: Node communication and membership within a Swarm are secure out of the box. SwarmKit uses mutual TLS for node authentication, role authorization and transport encryption, automating both certificate issuance and rotation.
- Simple: SwarmKit is operationally simple and minimizes infrastructure dependencies. It does not need an external database to operate.

**Docker Swarm Mode (Version 1.12 >)** *uses* Swarmkit libraries & functionality in order to make container orchestration over multiple hosts (a cluster) very simple & secure to operate. There is a new set of features (the main one being `docker swarm`) which are now built into Docker itself to allow you to initiate a new Swarm and deploy *tasks* (which are Docker containers in this case, but don't have to be, see *Swarmkit* above) to that cluster.

As mentioned on the **Docker Swarm** page, it is not being deprecated, and is still a viable method for Docker multi-host orchestration, but **Docker Swarm Mode** (which uses the **Swarmkit** libraries under the hood) is the recommended way to begin a new Docker project where orchestration over multiple hosts is required.

Comment: One more question, when you refer "`Version > 1.12`", it should contain `1.12`, right?

Answer (score 5):

As per this blog :

> Swarmkit used within Swarm Mode ( 1.12) and tightly integrated with Docker
>   Engine

https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/comparing-swarm-swarmkit-and-swarm-mode/

Comment: That's a very good article. The author uses "SwarmNext" for what everyone now calls "Swarm Mode".