# Is there a roadmap for docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is there a roadmap for swarm with regards to new features and future direction of the project? Some of us out here using swarm are starting to get concerned about Docker's future plans for swarm given all the focus from Docker seems to be around Kubernetes

Just as an example, looking at the recent 2018 Dockercon agenda there 67 Kubernetes references and only 11 for swarm.

What is the current and future roadmap for swarm?

Is swarm being put into a maintenance mode only in favor of Kubernetes?

Comment: https://blog.docker.com/2017/11/swarm-orchestration-in-docker-enterprise-edition/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest news, Docker Swarm is Dead.

News from Mirantis

> What About Docker Swarm?
>
> The primary orchestrator going forward is Kubernetes. Mirantis is
> committed to providing an excellent experience to all Docker
> Enterprise platform customers and currently expects to support Swarm
> for at least two years, depending on customer input into the roadmap.
> Mirantis is also evaluating options for making the transition to
> Kubernetes easier for Swarm users.

Reference : https://www.mirantis.com/blog/mirantis-acquires-docker-enterprise-platform-business/

It's important to know that, Docker swarm **≠** Docker swarm mode. Please read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039031/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-swarm-and-swarm-mode)

What is Legacy Docker Swarm. Read this please
https://docs.docker.com/swarm/overview/

Swarm Mode is built-in
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/

The good news is, **Swarm Mode** will live on.

Answer (score 3):

Swarm is alive and well. It’s open source and no road map that I know of. Lots of Swarm fans at dockercon. http://www.bretfisher.com/is-swarm-dead-answered-by-a-docker-captain/