# Difference between Docker Swarm vs Swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, service-discovery

What difference between initialization swarm over this commands:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <manager-ip>
docker -H <worker-ip> swarm join --token <worker-token>
```

And this one:

```
docker run swarm manage <consul-ip>
docker -H <worker-ip> run swarm join --advertise=<worker-ip> <consul-ip>
```

Why we need `swarm` image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Docker Swarm** (also Swarm classic) is fundamentally different from **Swarm Mode**. Native Swarm functionality will continue to be supported in Docker 1.12 release, this is done to preserve backward compatibility.

**Docker Swram (classic)**:

- Separate from Docker Engine and can run as Container
- Needs external KV store like Consul, etcd, Zookeeper

Usage example:

```
docker run swarm manage <consul-ip>
docker -H <worker-ip> run swarm join --advertise=<worker-ip> <consul-ip>
```

**Swarm Mode (new, preferable)**:

- Integrated inside Docker engine
- No need of separate external KV store

Usage example:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <manager-ip>
docker -H <worker-ip> swarm join --token <worker-token>
```

Source: [Comparing Swarm, Swarmkit and Swarm Mode](https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/comparing-swarm-swarmkit-and-swarm-mode/)

Great answer on another question like this one: [The relation between “docker/swarm” and “docker/swarmkit”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474424/the-relation-between-docker-swarm-and-docker-swarmkit?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

If you run using docker containers, you can have multiple instances of swarm running from one server. And moreover, the swarm network will run in a sandbox environment rather than on your host OS.

You need swarm image if you want to run it in a docker container.

Comment: I found very nice answer: [The relation between “docker/swarm” and “docker/swarmkit”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474424/the-relation-between-docker-swarm-and-docker-swarmkit?answertab=active#tab-top)