# docker run swarm create vs docker swarm init

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

While creating docker swarm cluster, I have came across following two commands:

- docker run swarm create
- docker swarm init

Both used for initializing Docker swarm cluster. Can any one explain what are different trade off parameter between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker run swarm create` will deploy standalone swarm (swarm-mode) in a container. Whereas `docker swarm init` will initiate swarm (swarm-kit) that is shipped built in `docker` container runtime.

The following answers does very well to explain the difference.
[The relation between "docker/swarm" and "docker/swarmkit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474424/the-relation-between-docker-swarm-and-docker-swarmkit)

But to simply specify the difference, one is tightly integrated with `docker` container runtime engine. The other runs inside the container.

Comment: I think it is a little bit confusing to associate the "standalone swarm" with "(swarm-mode)", as the (Docker) Swarm mode is the word [used by the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) for the new approach, while [they are using](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/) the term "Standalone Docker Swarm" for the old approach.